# How to create a double click event programmatically and dispatch on an image in ckeditor enabled area

Tags: javascript

I have an image placed in a CKEDITOR enabled area.I need to open image properties window of this image by dispatch a double click event on it.(event should create programmatically)
Tried this code

```
var evObj = new Event('dblclick');
    var $img = $('#'+divId, doc).find('img')[0];
    $img.dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

it shows return value undefined when debug the script

[Debug window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJV93.png)

Comment: What is exact error message you are getting?

Comment: `$('#'+divId, doc).find('img')[0].trigger('dblclick');` It will work if object exist in to the given dom.

Comment: Sorry, its not working. shows $('#'+divId, doc).find('img')[0].trigger is not a function

Comment: Anyone familiar with this type of code or same situation?